# Centroid equal to Arithmetic Mean?

Tags: geometry

Given a cloud of points in three dimensional space (with coordinates x,y,z), is the centroid for these points equal to the arithmetic mean of their coordinates?

Comment: Look for the definition of "centroid" in your book.  In my textbook, the answer is "yes" (if "cloud" means "finite set").

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i saw the wikipedia page, but wasn't sure if my interpretation was correct.

Answer (score 1):

The comments state that 'arithmetic mean of coordinates' is indeed the definition of the centroid.